# Sending email with attachments in PHP, only show characters no file attached

Tags: php, email, attachment

I have this problem in my web page, I need to send a file via email to someone, the problem that I have is that the mail arrives without an attachment and a lot of strange characters, I leave you my code:

```
$boundary='Datos Adjuntos';
$boundary.=" ".md5(time());
//Cabeceras del email               

$headers ="From: Example <name@example.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <name@example.com>\r\n";
//   $headers .="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";   
$headers .="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n\n";

$body="--". $boundary ."\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n\n";

$archivo=file_get_contents($dir."/".$handle->file_dst_name);

$archivo=chunk_split(base64_encode($archivo));

//Escritura del archivo adjunto
$body .= $body .$ContenidoString. "--" .$boundary. "\n";
//Content-Type: application/msword; name=\"nombre_archivo\"\r\n
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$body .=  "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$handle->file_dst_name."\"\r\n\n$archivo";

$body = $body . "--" . $boundary ."--";

Correo::Enviar("OPERACION","name@example.com", $body,$headers);
```

The `$ContentString` is the html of the email, I use the upload class to upload the file to the server and then send it, I leave you a piece of the email that I receive:
This is after all the other things lik e## e name and  ## e content of the email.

--Datos Adjuntos 1c436ca78c5925e7096267f0eae3a7d3 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="9cbdf187_3251_42e5_aeaa_84df343a227d_4.pdf" JVBERi0xLjQKJdP0zOEKMSAwIG9iago8PAovQ3JlYXRpb25EYXRlKEQ6MjAxMTA4MTYxNTEyNDIt MDUnMDAnKQovQ3JlYXRvcihQREZzaGFycCAxLjMuMTY4NC1nIFwod3d3LnBk

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel when there's lots of tried and tested code available that successfully does what you're trying to achieve? Just use [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html) or a similar component, and concentrate on solving your unique problems instead of those that have been solved over and over again...

Comment: You don't seem to have any HTML in your `text/html` portion of the message...

Comment: No I didn't put the HTML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you would be better to use a pre-built library as people are saying, if for some reason you can't/don't want to, you can try this:

**EDITED!!**

```
// Make a MIME boundary
$boundary = 'Datos_Adjuntos_'.md5(time());

// Message headers
$headers  = "From: Example <name@example.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <name@example.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";   
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n\r\n";

// For email clients that don't understand MIME messages
$body = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format. If you can read this, something went wrong or your mail client doesn't understand MIME messages.";

// HTML content
$body .= "\r\n--$boundary\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"\r\n\r\n";
$body .= $ContenidoString;

// Attachment
$body .= "\r\n--$boundary\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: application/msword\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$handle->file_dst_name\"\r\n\r\n";
$body .= chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents("$dir/$handle->file_dst_name")));

// Finish the MIME message
$body .= "\r\n--$boundary--";

// (Presumably) send the email
Correo::Enviar("OPERACION","name@example.com",$body,$headers);
```

Comment: I have tried it and it work's, so can you explain me what was wrong please, to understand y mistake and don't do it again and thanks

Comment: There were two major things: your `\r\n` (CRLF) sequences were wrong - some were missing, some in the wrong places, some were only `\n` (LF) where you need a full `\r\n`. But also this line: `$body .= $body .$ContenidoString. "--" .$boundary. "\n";` appends the entire body on to itself, whereas what you wanted was `$body .= $ContenidoString. "\r\n--" .$boundary. "\r\n";` or `$body = $body .$ContenidoString. "\r\n--" .$boundary. "\r\n";`. If you lay your code out one line at a time (as above) it makes it easier to spot things like this... :-D

Comment: Ohh thank you very much, the problem is that I was using the code of a guy in my work, and can I ask you one more thing, what means \r and \n because I never get it

Comment: `\r` is a carriage-return (**CR**) and `\n` is a new-line or line-feed (**LF**), together they are known as **CRLF**. They mean different things on different platforms - on a Mac, `\r` is the line terminating character sequence, or end-of-line (**EOL**). On Linux/Unix `\n` is the EOL, and on Windows `\r\n` is the EOL. In a MIME message, message lines (headers, boundaries) are separated with a CRLF. There should be a blank line between headers and content - this means the last header should be followed by two CRLFs, and a CRLF between the content and the boundary.

Comment: Thank you very much, I kind of understand, it's a little bit confuse but I think that's because I am starting with this

Comment: SUPER - this actually helped me to pinpoint where the similar problem in my own script is...thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use SwiftMailer
http://swiftmailer.org/
This php package will save you a lot of time, and make your life really easier for sending mails.
Here is how your code would look like :

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
->setSubject('Your subject')
->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))
->setBody('Here is the message itself')
->addPart('<q>Here is the message itself</q>', 'text/html')
->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('my-document.pdf'))
;
```

And you would be done !
Give it a try, I use it all the time